# Is there a way to have custom DTOs for each endpoint, without having a ton of DTO classes?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api-design

I have are large number of REST endpoints, written in Java & Spring. The endpoints mostly look like this simplified example.

- `GET /cars?` => Get all cards
- `GET /cars/<id>` => Get single car
- `PATCH /car/<id>` => update car
- `PATCH /cars-bulk` => update car (bulk)
- `POST /cars` => create car
- `POST /cars-bulk` => create cars (bulk)

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class CarDTO {
  private String id;
  private String make;
  private String model;
  private String owner;
  private boolean isAvailable;
}
```

And let's say I have this service signature:

```
public interface CarService {
  CarDTO getCarById(String id);
  List<CarDTO> getCars(CarDTO filter);
  CarDTO updateCar(CarDTO car);
  CarDTO createCar(CarDTO car);
  List<BulkUpdateResult> updateCars(List<CarDTO> car);
  List<BulkUpdateResult> createCars(List<CarDTO> car);
}
```

In this case, DTOs are shared across different service methods. This comes with the problem that the consumers of these interfaces don't know which fields they need to set in the DTO for each method call.

For example:

- `getCarById` and `getCars` calls returns all fields, except `isAvailable`
- `updateCar` / `updateCars` is only allowed to update the `owner` field
- `createCar` / `createCars` can set any field, except the `id` (generated by service)

This can be implemented using validators and manual description of the APIs, but I prefer to have self-explanatory call signatures for certain endpoints. If a field is not supposed to be produced or consumed, I don't want to make it part of the call signature.

One solution I have tried is to create DTOs (`CarGetDTO`, `CarUpdateDTO`, `CarCreateDTO`) for every endpoint like so:

```
public interface CarService {
  CarGetDTO getCarById(String id);
  List<CarGetDTO> getCars(CarGetDTO filter);
  CarGetDTO updateCar(CarUpdateDTO car);
  CarGetDTO createCar(CarUpdateDTO car);
  List<BulkUpdateResult> updateCars(List<CarCreateDTO> car);
  List<BulkUpdateResult> createCars(List<CarCreateDTO> car);
}
```

This however becomes incredibly complex with a large code base, code duplication and complex business requirements.

One way to solve this, that I can think of, is leverage polymorphism, but it makes the code mode complex and harder to understand.

```
public abstract class CarDTO {
  private String owner;
}

public class CarCreateDTO extends CarDTO  {
  private String make;
  private String model;
}

public class CarGetDTO extends CarCreateDTO  {
  private String id; // duplicate code
}

public class CarUpdateDTO extends CarCreateDTO  {
  private String id; // duplicate code
  private boolean isAvailable;
}
```

Are there any better, scalable patterns, of defining custom DTOs, without having to define each and every parameter and return type, perhaps through code generation?

Comment: Your "get" case is usually handled by "filters" rather than DTOs; having a look at Querydsl (which is directly supported by Spring with MVC argument resolvers) might be instructive.